# How to translate "merchant" into Brazilian Portuguese?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

A few examples to better make sense of what I am asking are:

> Please provide me with your merchant ID.
>
> Can you please provide me with your Merchant code?
>
> Enter Merchant ID
>
> Merchant Account ID

Answer (score 2):

If `merchant` could be replaced with `seller`, as in "person who's selling something", the best translations would be `vendedor` or `lojista`. Keep in mind `vendedor` is a gendered word that could pose an issue to your translation.

If it's supposed to mean `shop manager`, as in "person who can make decisions about the shop", then `comerciante` would be preferable.

Comment: Yeah, it can't be replaced because its dealing with online retailers, web shop owners and all types of merchants.

Comment: @Hugo definitely `comerciante`, then. The other ones imply the individual is not the one responsible for the store. I'll edit it to clarify.

Comment: "comerciante" is what came to mind first.